# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap Enabling Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I want to generate a form like entering the number of rows and columns and it will represents the required number of rows and columns in the next action.

Suppose the number of rows I enter is 4 and columns is 5. The right most columns becomes the most bottom below the final row. I don't want like that, I want it to enable horizontal scroll bar. Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Capacity; i++) // Columns Capacity is 5
        {
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Rows.Capacity; k++) //Rows Capacity is 4
                    {
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
                        <br />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, the output becomes like shown below:

[image]

I want the 5th column to be horizontal scroll bar enabled. Thanks

Comment: This is what twitter-bootstrap was designed to do - to wrap "rows" if they are too wide.  Just use `<table><tbody><tr><td>` if you don't want the rows to wrap.

Comment: Or, set the width on your container to `input width * number of columns` and style `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: Please can you elaborate the second point and apply it to my code. Using table is a little bit long process. Thanks

Comment: Just realised your cols/rows are around the wrong way.  I wondered why the whole last column wrapped to the bottom rather than wrapping each last column within the 'row' as normal bootstrap.

Comment: start with not using bootstrap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the width on your container so that it doesn't wrap, eg:

```
@{ 
    // standard col-md-3 form-control width, but needs to be hardcoded here
    // doesn't need to be exact and should include the padding/margin
    var inputwidth = 239;  
    var width = inputwidth * Model.Columns.Capacity;
}
<div class="container" style='width:@(width)px;overflow-y:auto'>
```

Use `overflow-y:auto` so that the scrollbar is only shown if needed

The recommended solution is to switch rows/cols and use a table as you're not using bootstrap's responsive features in this case.

---

**Edit:** As requested, here's an equivalent version using tables - set the bootstrap table classes as required

```
<div class="container" style='width:@(240 * Model.Columns.Capacity)px;overflow-y:auto'>
<table style='width:100%' class='table table-striped table-condensed'>
  <tbody>
    @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Rows.Capacity; k++) //Rows Capacity is 4
    {
      <tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Columns.Capacity; i++) // Columns Capacity is 5
        {
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control col-md-3" />
          </td>
        }
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, actually it does enable horizontal scroll bar. But it doesn't actually extend the number of columns more than 4. If the capacity of columns gets greater than 4. Waiting for you help.

Comment: Well, bootstrap is divided into 12 columns, if each one takes up 3 (`col-md-3`), then you can only have 4... (3x4=12)   You could change `col-md-3` to `col-md-1`, but then you'll get stuck at 12 again.

Comment: Thanks it really helping me, but what if I don't use bootstrap in order to overcome this situation? Can you provide me the solution that solves my exact problem without using bootstrap and get the required number of columns with scroll bars. I'll be very thankful to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks brother, you rocked. :)